# Can an American own part of a Canadian-based corporation?

Tags: united-states, canada, business, ontario, equity

Combination of New York State (USA) and Ontario (CAN) jurisdictions here.

If a New Yorker/American wishes to take partial ownership (equity) in an Ontario-based corporation, are there any special legal considerations to take?

- Is it even possible for an American to do this? Or would he/she need Canadian/dual citizenship to own part of a Canadian-based corporation?
- Besides normal filing procedures, are there any additional forms/filings/steps an American must do (with either government) to become owner of a Canadian-based corporation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, no special paperwork is required for an American to own shares in a Canadian corporation.

Comment: Thanks @ohwilleke (+1) -- and its completely legal without any special constraints?

Comment: @smeeb It is legal. Figuring out the tax implications is no cakewalk, however, particularly because the entire world of international corporate tax law has been turned upside down by U.S. legislation passed today that takes effect on January 1, 2018.